# How to remove whitespaces and newlines from every value in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, strip

I have a `JSON` file that has the following structure:

```
{
    "name":[
        {
            "someKey": "\n\n   some Value   "
        },
        {
            "someKey": "another value    "
        }
    ],
    "anotherName":[
        {
            "anArray": [
                {
                    "key": "    value\n\n",
                    "anotherKey": "  value"
                },
                {
                    "key": "    value\n",
                    "anotherKey": "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to `strip` off all he whitespaces and newlines for every value in the `JSON` file. Is there some way to iterate over each element of the dictionary and the nested dictionaries and lists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Now I want to strip off all he whitespaces and newlines for every value in the JSON file

Using `pkgutil.simplegeneric()` to create a helper function `get_items()`:

```
import json
import sys
from pkgutil import simplegeneric

@simplegeneric
def get_items(obj):
    while False: # no items, a scalar object
        yield None

@get_items.register(dict)
def _(obj):
    return obj.items() # json object. Edit: iteritems() was removed in Python 3

@get_items.register(list)
def _(obj):
    return enumerate(obj) # json array

def strip_whitespace(json_data):
    for key, value in get_items(json_data):
        if hasattr(value, 'strip'): # json string
            json_data[key] = value.strip()
        else:
            strip_whitespace(value) # recursive call


data = json.load(sys.stdin) # read json data from standard input
strip_whitespace(data)
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

Note: [`functools.singledispatch()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools#functools.singledispatch) function (Python 3.4+) would allow to use `collections`' [`MutableMapping/MutableSequence`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) instead of `dict/list` here.

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/Vfc6UW)

```
{
  "anotherName": [
    {
      "anArray": [
        {
          "anotherKey": "value", 
          "key": "value"
        }, 
        {
          "anotherKey": "value", 
          "key": "value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "name": [
    {
      "someKey": "some Value"
    }, 
    {
      "someKey": "another value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if instead of using sys, I'd want to clean a file, meaning read from it and write back to a new json file? I somehow can't get it working. `sys.stdin` / `sys.stdout` is so alien to me and I feel like your solution is specifically designed to work with it alone.

Comment: @TobiasKolb `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` are ordinary file objects by default (exactly the type of objects that are returned by the builtin `open()` function) i.e., if you know how to work with files in Python, you know how to work with `sys.stdin`/`sys.stdout`. Though you don't need to modify the source to read json data from a file and write the result to a new file: `< input.json ./script-from-the-answer > output.json`

Answer (score 6):

Parse the file using [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json
file = file.replace('\n', '')    # do your cleanup here
data = json.loads(file)
```

then walk through the resulting data structure.

Comment: This won't work: The newlines are actually the characters \ and n, so you need to replace \\n with ''. Also, this won't remove the white space.

Comment: You can customize the "cleanup" line as needed.  My version of Python cleaned up the white space just fine.  You can clean up the values as you walk through 'data'.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most efficient process, but it works.  I copied that sample into a file named `json.txt`, then read it, deserialized it with `json.loads()`, and used a pair of functions to recursively clean it and everything inside it.

```
import json

def clean_dict(d):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            clean_list(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            clean_dict(value)
        else:
            newvalue = value.strip()
            d[key] = newvalue

def clean_list(l):
    for index, item in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            clean_dict(item)
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            clean_list(item)
        else:
            l[index] = item.strip()

# Read the file and send it to the dict cleaner
with open("json.txt") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print "before..."
print data, "\n"

clean_dict(data)

print "after..."
print data
```

The result...

```
before...
{u'anotherName': [{u'anArray': [{u'anotherKey': u'  value', u'key': u'    value\n\n'}, {u'anotherKey': u'value', u'key': u'    value\n'}]}], u'name': [{u'someKey': u'\n\n   some Value   '}, {u'someKey': u'another value    '}]} 

after...
{u'anotherName': [{u'anArray': [{u'anotherKey': u'value', u'key': u'value'}, {u'anotherKey': u'value', u'key': u'value'}]}], u'name': [{u'someKey': u'some Value'}, {u'someKey': u'another value'}]}
```

Comment: don't use `eval()` for json text. You could use `json.loads()` instead

Comment: You probably also want to strip values in a list (`else` clause is missing in `clean_list()`). `"".join(f.readlines())` should be just `f.read()` or you could pass a file object directly `json.load(f)`. `value.replace("\\n", "")` is incorrect: "\n" - newline, "\\n" - two chars; anyway `.strip()` removes any leading/trailing whitespace including newlines. The copying `d.items()` and `l[:]` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tips.  I've updated the code again.  FWIW, I originally had an `else` clause in `clean_list()` for cleaning individual list items, but as the sample JSON data didn't use it, I took it out before posting my original answer.

Comment: +1: it looks ok now. Note: `l[index] == item` so you could use `item` as rvalue instead of `l[index]`. To close a file automatically, you could use `with open(filename) as file: ...` it will close the file even if an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks.  Will fix the `l[index]` issue now.  Not sure how I didn't catch that one myself.  Regarding `with`, I've been under the impression for who-knows-how-long that it only worked in Python 3+. Just searched and found that it was added in 2.5.  Not sure where my memory is pulling the 3+ reference from, but I'll fix that as well.  Thanks much for the instruction!