# Pythonic isinstance on floats and ints

Tags: python, duck-typing

Say you have a function:

```
def divide(a, b):
    return a / b
```

This will obviously give a different result if `a` and `b` are `float`, `int`, or a combination. If you only care about the situation when `a` and `b` are floats, what is the best way to deal with this?

i)

```
def divide(a, b):
    if not isinstance(a, float):
        raise TypeError('a must be a float')
    if not isinstance(b, float):
        raise TypeError('b must be a float')
    return a / b
```

ii)

```
def divide(a, b):
    return float(a) / float(b)
```

iii) something else?

My preference is for ii), but a colleague argues that if you are using `a` and `b` elsewhere, then i) is more likely to prevent bugs.

This is obviously a somewhat trivial example, but my colleague has much more experience with `C` and I am struggling to explain why using `isinstance` doesn't really fit with duck-typing and that having it permeate through in our python code is not great.

Comment: You only need to convert one of the operands: `return float(a) / b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option could be

```
def divide(a, b):
    return a * 1.0 / b
```

or

```
from __future__ import division

def divide(a, b):
    return a / b
```

Comment: The second option is the *best* way to deal with this, as it's consistent and future-proof.

Comment: @glglgl I think the OP was asking about 'enforcing' that a function accept only certain types of parameters. He's simply using divide as an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do true division, regardless of Python version and don't want to use future imports, then an alternative is:

```
from operator import truediv
print truediv(4, 2)
# 2.0
```

Which will always do true division and return a float regardless of its input (given an int/float)... Passing fractions/complex/decimals will have other output!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using:

```
def divide(a, b):
    return float(a) / float(b)
```

Probably one conversion to float would also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `divide()` is just an example of a function that might *silently* produce a wrong result given arguments with unexpected types.

To avoid hardcoding the type check in the function, a generic function could be used e.g., [`get_items()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101711/4279) allows to treat both json object and json array uniformly (compare `convert_decimal()` implementations: [the one with `isinstance()` calls vs. another with the generic `get_items()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081150/4279)).

If the dispatching based on only the type of the first argument is not enough; see [Five-minute Multimethods in Python](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605) by by Guido van van Rossum.