# Convert python decimal to string in deeply nested and unpredictable list

Tags: python, recursion, nested, decimal, nested-lists

I am trying to loop through every value in a deeply nested/mixed list and convert any Decimal instances to string so that I can store them in mongo.

My attempt at recursion reached the max depth. I would like to solve this iteratively or in a performant manner.

This doesn't seem to work but is my latest attempt:

```
def convert_decimals(root_obj):
    objs_to_convert = [root_obj]

    while objs_to_convert:
        obj = objs_to_convert.pop(0)
        for k, v in enumerate(obj):

            if len(v):
                objs_to_convert.append(v)
            elif isinstance(v, Decimal):
                obj[k] = str(v)
```

Sample Input:

```
[
    {
        'Payments': {
            'Payment': Decimal('495.64'),
            'IsCapped': True,
            'OtherFees': Decimal('0'),
            'CapCostTotal': Decimal('27900'),
            'Name': 'TestData',
            'Program': {
                'ProgramName': u'AST',
                'Description': None
            },
            'Rate': Decimal('0.0254'),
            'APR': Decimal('2.54'),
            'AppliedIds': [

            ],
            'Tax': Decimal('0')
        }
    }
]
```

After conversion, the decimal instances should be strings

Comment: Perhaps supply an example input/output, even if it is too small to blow the stack.

Comment: updated answer to include sample input

Comment: Have you tried to provide `default` parameter to handle `Decimal` during `json.dump`?

Comment: I haven't. I thought of json dumping and loading before sending to mongo. Could you provide an example, I tried the method suggested on the python docs page without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert `Decimal` during `json.dump()` using `default` parameter:

```
import json
import sys
from decimal import Decimal

def default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return str(obj)
    else:
        raise TypeError(obj)

# convert during dump
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2, default=default)
```

To modify `data` inplace:

```
import json
import sys
from collections import MutableMapping, MutableSequence
from decimal import Decimal

def convert_decimal(json_data):
    stack = [json_data]
    while stack:
        json_data = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(json_data, MutableMapping): # json object
            it = json_data.items()
        elif isinstance(json_data, MutableSequence): # json array
            it = enumerate(json_data)
        else: # scalar data
            continue

        for k, v in it:
            if isinstance(v, Decimal):
                json_data[k] = str(v)
            else:
                stack.append(v)


# convert inplace
convert_decimal(data)
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

Both scripts produce the same output:

```
[
  {
    "Payments": {
      "OtherFees": "0", 
      "APR": "2.54", 
      "Rate": "0.0254", 
      "IsCapped": true, 
      "Name": "TestData", 
      "Program": {
        "Description": null, 
        "ProgramName": "AST"
      }, 
      "AppliedIds": [], 
      "CapCostTotal": "27900", 
      "Tax": "0", 
      "Payment": "495.64"
    }
  }
]
```

You could simplify `convert_decimal()` if you use a [generic `get_items()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101711/4279):

```
def convert_decimal(json_data):
    stack = [json_data]
    while stack:
        json_data = stack.pop()
        for k, v in get_items(json_data):
            if isinstance(v, Decimal):
                json_data[k] = str(v)
            else:
                stack.append(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert decimals to strings, but recursively apply your function to the contents of lists and the values of dictionaries, otherwise return objects unchanged? Then do that:

```
def strip_decimals(o):
    if type(o) == Decimal:
        return str(o)
    elif type(o) == list:
        return map(strip_decimals, o)
    elif type(o) == dict:
        return dict([(k, strip_decimals(v)) for k, v in o.iteritems()])
    else:
        return o
```

Results in:

```
[{'Payments': {'APR': '2.54',
           'AppliedIds': [],
           'CapCostTotal': '27900',
           'IsCapped': True,
           'Name': 'TestData',
           'OtherFees': '0',
           'Payment': '495.64',
           'Program': {'Description': None, 'ProgramName': u'AST'},
           'Rate': '0.0254',
           'Tax': '0'}}]
```

Comment: Won't this still run amuck of recursion issues if he has really deep structures?

Comment: @TravisGriggs `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)` or explicitly keep your own stack in a `list`.

Comment: As a note about recursion limits, Python's default is 1,000 levels of recursion. If you have a data structure that is more than 1,000 levels in depth... I'm terribly sorry you have a data structure shaped that way. For the rest of the world, it's incredibly unlikely you'll bump against that ceiling with this function.