# Python: How to customize default bytes handling in simplejson.dumps()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplejson

Is there a clean way to customize handling of `bytes` objects when using `simplejson.dumps()` in recent versions of `simplejson`? (I am using 3.5.3)

I tried using the `default` attribute, which works fine in `json.dumps()` and older versions of `simplejson` (<3.0.0?). However, recent versions of `simplejson` attempt to decode the `bytes` with the specified encoding, so the `bytes` skips the `default` handler.

I also tried setting `encoding=None`, but this caused an exception.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import json
import simplejson
from decimal import Decimal

def _encoder(data):
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        return 'BYTES!'
    if isinstance(data, Decimal):
        return 'DECIMAL!'
    raise TypeError('No json encoder for {}'.format(type(data)))

data = {'d': Decimal(1), 'b': b'test'}

print(json.dumps(data, default=_encoder))
# works as expected: {"d": "DECIMAL!", "b": "BYTES!"}

print(simplejson.dumps(data, default=_encoder, use_decimal=False))
# does not work for bytes: {"d": "DECIMAL!", "b": "test"}
```

`simplejson` allows you to extend `JSONEncoder`, but there doesn't seem a good place to hook into the encoding of a single, nested object. For example, in my debugging, `JSONEncoder::iterencode` handed off an entire dictionary to an outside function (`_iterencode`).

Comment: json format is defined for Unicode text. Decode bytes yourself. Here's [code example that calls `.strip()` method using recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17101711/4279) and [here's iterative version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081150/4279) -- you could call `.decode()` on bytes instances instead.

Comment: I am not trying to decode the bytes object. It is a binary object that cannot be decoded into text.

Comment: then you can't store it in json format. Any method would require to convert the bytes into Unicode.

Comment: That is why I am trying to override the conversion for it, so I can convert it into a special format dictionary.

Comment: ok. Call `convert_to_special_format_dictionary()` instead of `.decode()` in the above example. Look at how `convert_decimal()` is used in [the previously linked code example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081150/4279). You could provide  a minimal `data` object as an example and the corresponding json text that you expect to get and what you actually get with your current code instead, to make the question clearer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing now as a workaround (recursively converting all of the bytes instances before calling json.dumps). But I am hoping to find a cleaner method such as a hook somewhere in simplejson. If such a feature is not there, I think the developers left it out by mistake, since many binary formats are non-textual and would need to be converted manually. In other words, the answer to this question is not essential to my code - it is more of an "am I missing something?" question.

Comment: `simplejson` works on both Python 2 and 3. `json` module in Python 2 doesn't allow to customize `str` handling too, try `json.dumps([b'abc'])` on Python 2. If `bytes` object in your compound object is not an encoded text then use a custom class (+`for_json()` or `default`) or convert it to "special dictionary" without a custom class before `dumps()`. btw, your question might be clearer if you use "customize default bytes handling" instead of *"override encoding of bytes"* that might be confused with "character encoding".

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure how to phrase it. I've updated the question. Wrapping would work, yes, although it would be similar to pre-conversion for my code. I see where you are going with python2 (that they are trying to make simplejson work similarly between 2 and 3, right?). But in python2 `bytes` is an alias for `str`, while in python3 `bytes` is a separate type, which to me would indicate special treatment. But from everything you've said and from the lack of answers - it looks like my only options are to pre-convert outside of `simplejson` or switch to `json`.

Comment: it wouldn't hurt if you open an issue about changing `simplejson` to reject  `bytes` by default on Python 3 if `encoding=None`.