# Best practice to write generic numerical functions that work with both ndarray and MaskedArray

Tags: python, numpy, coding-style

Is there a more beautiful way than:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma
def foo(x):
    pkg = ma if isinstance(x, ma.MaskedArray) else np
    return pkg.apply_along_axis(bar, -1, x)
```

I feel it not Pythonic, in terms of trying to make the most out of polymorphism.

**EDIT**

The above code snippet is just a demo to highlight the fact that `np` and `ma` have highly similar (designed on purpose) interface (e.g., `apply_along_axis`), but under different namespace.

Comment: What is nonpythonic? Completely valid code if it serves your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`isinstance()` is fine as it is here.

You could make it implicit if you'd like using a [single-dispatch generic function](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools#functools.singledispatch):

```
from pkgutil import simplegeneric

import numpy as np
from numpy import ma

@simplegeneric
def pkg(obj):
    return np # use numpy by default

@pkg.register(ma.MaskedArray)
def _(x):
    return ma

def foo(x):
    return pkg(x).apply_along_axis(bar, -1, x)
```

Here's another example of [generic function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101711/4279).