# Get the query execution time in json output

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

```
from flask import Flask, request
import src.dbcon as db
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    id = request.args.get('id')
    query = "select * from employee where id= {id} limit 2;"
    with db.sample(query.format(id=request.args.get('id'))) as data:
        return data
  am returning data in json format.
```

1)i have to return query execution time along with json data.
   sample: "query_execution_time”: 2345,
2)In json output i am getting some void space
 [{"id": "10000", "roll_no": "02V              }] 
so how to remove these space?

```
def getcursor_read(query): 
    a=read_create_conn(config=configuration) 
    print("Created read connection,") 
    con = a.getconn() 
    print(query) 

    try: 
        cur = con.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) 
        cur.execute(query) 
        print("Handed read connection!") 
        data =cur.fetchall() 
        json_data = json.dumps([dict(ix) for ix in data]) 
        print(json_data) 
        #con.commit() 
    except: 
        con.rollback() 
    finally: 
        a.putconn(con) yield json_data
```

How to pass this `data[0]['execution_time'] = query_execution_time` in the above function?

Comment: add a new element as `data[0]['execution_time'] = query_execution_time`, this would add 'execution_time' in json itself. For 2nd part of question I suggest you can use `json.dumps(separators=(',', ':'))` but if the whitespace problem is more complicated than that then you might have to follow this approach [Remove Whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098553/how-to-remove-whitespaces-and-newlines-from-every-value-in-a-json-file)

Comment: @UtkarshShekhar  def getcursor_read(query): a=read_create_conn(config=configuration) print("Created read connection") con = a.getconn() print(query) try: cur = con.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) cur.execute(query) print("Handed read connection!") data =cur.fetchall() json_data = json.dumps([dict(ix) for ix in data]) print(json_data) #con.commit() except: con.rollback() finally: a.putconn(con) yield json_data how to pass this data[0]['execution_time'] = query_execution_time in the above function?

Comment: Don't paste Code as Comment, [Edit] your Question accordingly.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show at least 3 Lines of Data from `json_data` to tell you How To add `query_execution_time`.