# Scrapy returns garbage data such as spaces and newlines. How shall I filter these?

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a spider and it returns me data which is littered with spaces and newline characters. The newline characters also caused `extract()` method to return as a list. How do I filter these before it touch the selector? Filtering these after `extract()` is called breaks the DRY principle as there are a lot of data from a page I need to extract that is attributeless which makes the only way to parse it is through indexing.

How do I filter these?

[Source](https://github.com/ojiii/malscraper/blob/master/malscraper/malscraper/spiders/animespider.py)

it returns bad data like this

```
{ 'aired': ['\n  ', '\n  Apr 3, 2016 to Jun 26, 2016\n  '],  
 'broadcast': [],  'duration': ['\n  ', '\n  24 min. per ep.\n  '],  'episodes': ['\n  ', '\n  13\n  '],  'favourites': ['\n  ', '\n  22,673\n'],  'genres': ['Action', 'Comedy', 'School', 'Shounen', 'Super Power'],  'image_url': ['https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg',
               'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/10/78745.jpg'],  'licensors': ['Funimation'],  'members': ['\n  ', '\n    818,644\n'],  'popularity': ['\n  ', '\n  #21\n'],  'premiered': ['Spring 2016'],  'producers': ['Dentsu',
               'Mainichi Broadcasting System',
               'Movic',
               'TOHO animation',
               'Shueisha'],  'ranked': ['\n  ', '\n  #135', '\n    ', '\n'],  'rating': ['\n  ', '\n  PG-13 - Teens 13 or older\n  '],  'score': ['8.44'],  'source': ['\n  ', '\n  Manga\n  '],  'status': ['\n  ', '\n  Finished Airing\n  '],  'studios': ['Bones'],  'title': 'Boku no Hero Academia',  'type': ['TV']}
```

Edit: The link to source code is different from the time of posting, to see the code back then take a look at commit [faae4aff1f998f5589fab1616d21c7afc69e03eb](https://github.com/ojiii/malscraper/blob/faae4aff1f998f5589fab1616d21c7afc69e03eb/malscraper/malscraper/spiders/animespider.py)

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: see source, its a direct link to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you could try using xpaths normalize-space

`mal_item['aired'] = border_class.xpath('normalize-space(.//div[11]/text())').extract()`

*untested, but seems legit.

For a more general answer, `yourString.strip('someChar')` or `yourString.replace('this','withThis')` works well (but in the case of [operating with json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098553/how-to-remove-whitespaces-and-newlines-from-every-value-in-a-json-file) it might not be as efficient as other approaches). If those characters are present in the original data, you need to manually remove them or skip them.

Comment: That's a great xpath function. It kind of solve another problem of mine because of another method I used to filter that. Instead of a bunch of same statements to insert into items I used a for loop. The only problem is if they ever add a new data with class="dark_text" on the border_class, it will break. I might push the code right now so feel free to look at it if you want. it looks ugly, I will refractor it tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

> The newline characters also caused extract() method to return as a list

It is not the line breaks that is a cause of such behavior but the way nodes appear in the document tree. Text nodes which are separated by element nodes such as for example `<a>, <br>, <hr>` are seen as separate entities and scrappy will yield them as such (in fact `extract()` is supposed to always return a list, even when only a single node was selected). XPath has several basic value processing / filtering functions but it's very limited.

> Filtering these after extract() is called breaks the DRY principle

You seem convinced that the only correct way to filter these outputs is by doing it within the selector expression. But it's no use to be so stringent about the principles, you are selecting text nodes from inside your target nodes, and these are bound to have excessive whitespace or be scattered all around their containers. XPath filtering by content is very sluggish and as such it should be done outside of it. Post processing scraped fields is a common practice. You might want to read about scrapy [loaders and processors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors).

Otherwise the simplest way is:

```
# import re
...


def join_clean(texts):
    return re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', ' '.join(texts)).strip()

...

mal_item['type'] = join_clean(border_class.xpath('.//div[8]/a/text()').extract())
```

Comment: I did solve this by applying DRY to most of the previous code, so now I apply the filter after I extract them. Please look at my code again and see what you think. The loader and processors, looks interesting, I will play with it a bit.

Comment: I'm afraid it looks far worse then the previous version to me. You reduced the number of lines and visual "repeatedness" with a dense structure that is a lot harder to grasp and will be harder to maintain in case site changes the html. Also trusting the keys present in the markup to relate 1:1 to your expected item schema is not the best idea. Frankly, I think clarity beats DRY in a lot of cases, and when adhering to design principles this strongly one might end up spending inadequate amount of time writing very sophisticated but 100% redundant code stunts. Apologies if coming off a bit harsh.

Comment: May have spoken too soon, it's actually fine the way you are doing it. Disregard the ranting tone.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was also explaining in my post, but I think the use of strip is explained better here in this context.

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you tell me why you did a "360" on your first statement? I do agree it is harder to read, especially if you don't refer to the HTML document, I will try to refractor and add some comments. However, I prefer this method since the first method uses indexing which will break it if a new child div is added in places other than the last child.

Comment: @KuoChongYii, I didn't pay enough attention to what is actually going on in your code, so jumped onto wrong conclusions, but the thing you're doing is common when handling attributeless key-value pairs inside html, I usually pull em in a temp dict however and then pull from it explicitly (e.g. https://hastebin.com/iwikuvidoz.py)

Comment: ah I understand