# REGEX remove whitespace from JSON ignoring values

Tags: json, regex

RE: [How to remove whitespaces and newlines from every value in a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098553/how-to-remove-whitespaces-and-newlines-from-every-value-in-a-json-file)

I want to do the opposite, and ignore values or groups but remove all whitespace from the structure of a JSON, for example:

Input:

```
{
    "1": "This   is        a string",
    "AnInt": 123,
    "3": [6, 9, 429]
}
```

Goal Output:

```
{"1":"This   is        a string","AnInt":123,"3":[6,9,429]}
```

I can get close with

`\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)`

but it does't remove the spaces in and around the group in `3`

When I modify the REGEX to capture around the square brackets for groups it breaks completely `\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)*(?=(?:[^[]*[[^[]*][^]]*)*$)*`

Comment: Replace all `\s*(\S+|\"[^\"]*\")\s*` with `$1`. Better readable.

Comment: Could you perhaps consider parsing the JSON and then re-stringifying it without padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to match whitespaces outside quotes:

```bash
\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

If using a regex engine with support of possessive quantifier:

```bash
\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*+$)
```

**Output:**

```bash
{"1":"This   is        a string","AnInt":123,"3":[6,9,429]}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ymb9Bi/1)

Replacement would be just an empty string.

This regex will split on whitespaces if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are **even number of quotes** after matching 1+ whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. I will learn more about lookahead's to understand this better for future. Cheers!

Comment: Can get this working with golang, perl syntax (?= not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in two steps.

First, remove all line breaks

```
\n
```

https://regex101.com/r/zxoT1g/1

Second, remove all spaces

```
({|"|,)([ ]{2,})
```

https://regex101.com/r/psXFCu/1

Answer (score 0):

The other answers (so far) fail to handle nested quotes.  For example...

```
{"foo bar": "This is a \"string inside a string\" x y \\", "my test": "a b c"}
```

is valid json.  And the only unnecessary spaces are just after the colons and comma.

I don't know for sure how to deal with this.  If this never happens in your application, you can just ignore the problem?

Below is a hack that *might* work...

1. hide all escaped backslashes (use regex to change all the double backslashes to "J$D&@Q!")
2. similarly hide all escaped quotes
3. use anubhava's thing... \s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$) to remove spaces
4. unhide the escaped backslashes and quotes.

Probably that will work.  But I wouldn't recommend it.   Much better to just parse the fricking json using a standard parser (available in any language) and then stringify it again using compressed flag!

Don't reinvent the wheel.