HMAC SHA-256 giving different results
I'm trying to replicate the result of this site here with python hmac/hashlib.
I have a json object that I need to get the hash of:
{"event":"transaction:status_update","date":"2017-08-30T13:47:42+00:00","transactions":[{"id":"asdlfjasdf93","state":"COMPLETED","label":"Marked as review"},{"id":"fd09dfad8df9","state":"REVOKED","label":"Review complete."}]}

and below is the code I'm using to do so.
import hmac, hashlib

signature = hmac.new(
        bytes('mykey', 'utf-8'), 
        msg = message.encode('utf-8'),
        digestmod = hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()

The issue I'm having is the site I linked probably does something with the string that python isn't doing, or vice versa, and I can't figure out how to format the string from the json. I've tried json.dumps(json_obj), str(json_obj), repr(json_obj). I can't figure out what it is I'm missing, but the hash on the site and on python don't match.
To be clear, this is a hash to be received through an external API and the site gave the correct hash, so I know I need to replicate this.

I can't reproduce the issue, both your code and the website give the same hash for that JSON string. My guess is your method of stringifying the object changes the order of the properties (which is allowed as JSON objects are unordered). Can't you prevent the website response from being parsed to an object and take the literal response body?

@robertklep, appreciated. you're onto the problem here, and this was what I was missing. If I simply put the json object into a hard coded string from the start, it matches. So something is happening to the object that's changing it up.

It seems since the object gets read into python as a json, it inserts spaces after commas/colons, then when I read the string back, those are there, but not in the original payload, hence the mismatch. This post gives a nice solution to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319317/regex-remove-whitespace-from-json-ignoring-values
