# Make my_average(a, b) work with any a and b for which f_add and d_div are defined. As well as builtins

Tags: python, python-3.x

In short: what I want is for the majority of mathematical functions I've written (e.g., `my_average(a, b)`) to work with any `a` and `b` for which an `f_add` and `f_div` have been defined. Without overloading + and / and without breaking `my_average(built_in_type, built_in_type)` In python 3.

Specifically, I'm working with instances of a Pigment object I have created. Overloading operators for these objects in not straightforward. For instance:

The difference (for distance purposes) between two instances might be `a.lab - b.lab`. (The Lab colorspace has a good correlation between perceptive and Euclidian distance.)

The sum (for mixing purposes) of two instances might be `a.srgb + b.srgb`. (The srgb colorspace is linear and appropriate for mathematical manipulation.)

For other purposes, sum and difference might mean something else.

So, duck typing in my existing modules wont work.

```
pigment_instance.distance(self, b)
pigment_instance.mix(self, b)
```

are fine as long as I don't mind re-writing every function (as a method) I need every time I have a new object like this. What I'd like to do is rewrite my functions just once more to be more robust.

I've tried a few things:

```
class Averager():
    __init__(self, f_mix, f_distance):
        self.f_mix = f_mix
        ...
    def __call__(self, a, b):
        # return the average calculated with self.f_something functions
```

That works OK, but I just end up burying an entire module in a class.

```
def mix(a, b, f_mix=lambda x, y: x + y, f_distance=lambda x, y: x - y)
# or, same as above with decorators.
```

Again, works OK, but I've got to keep the long default arguments or supply an f_add every time I want to calculate 2+2.

```
def pigment_functions(f_mix, f_distance):
    return [
        functools.partial(mix, f_mix=somefunc, f_distance=somefunc),
        functools.partial(distance, f_mix=somefunc, f_distance=somefunc)]

mix, difference = pigment_functions(f_mix, f_distance)
```

A similar choice to the second.

```
def mix(a, b):
    try: a + b
    except TypeError: # look for some global f_mix
```

Also works OK, but I've got global variables and a mess inside every function

Which of these (or something else) makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `my_average(a, b)` that is implemented in terms of `add` and `div` functions e.g.:

```
def my_average(a, b):
    return div(add(a, b), 2)
```

then to provide different implementations for different types, you could use [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch):

```
import functools

@singledispatch
def div(x, y:int): # default implementation
    raise NotImplementedError('for type: {}'.format(type(x)))

@div.register(Divisible) # anything with __truediv__ method
def _(x, y):
    return x / y

@singledispatch
def add(a, b): 
    raise NotImplementedError('for type: {}'.format(type(a)))

@add.register(Addable) # anything with __add__ method
def _(a, b):
    return a + b
```

where `Addable`, `Divisable` could be defined as:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Divisible(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """Anything with __truediv__ method."""
    __slots__ = ()
    __hash__ = None # disable default hashing

    @abstractmethod
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        """Return self / other."""

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Divisible:
            if any("__truediv__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented

class Addable(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """Anything with __add__ method."""
    __slots__ = ()
    __hash__ = None # disable default hashing

    @abstractmethod
    def __add__(self, other):
        """Return self + other."""

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Addable:
            if any("__add__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented
```

#### Example

```
>>> isinstance(1, Addable) # has __add__ method
True
>>> isinstance(1, Divisible) # has __truediv__ method
True
>>> my_average(1, 2)
1.5
>>> class A:
...   def __radd__(self, other):
...     return D(other + 1)
...
>>> isinstance(A(), Addable)
False
>>> _ = Addable.register(A) # register explicitly
>>> isinstance(A(), Addable)
True
>>> class D:
...   def __init__(self, number):
...     self.number = number
...   def __truediv__(self, other): 
...     return self.number / other
...
>>> isinstance(D(1), Divisible) # via issubclass hook
True
>>> my_average(1, A())
1.0
>>> my_average(A(), 1) # no A.__div__
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'A' and 'int'
```

Builtin numbers such as `int` define `__add__`, `__truediv__` method so they are supported automatically. As class `A` shows, you could use classes even if they don't define the specific methods such as `__add__` by calling `.register` method explicitly if they still can be used in the given implementation.

Use `add.register` and `div.register` to define implementations for other types if necessary e.g.:

```
@div.register(str)
def _(x, y):
    return x % y
```

After that:

```
>>> my_average("%s", "b") # -> `("%s" + "b") % 2`
'2b'
```

Comment: That's THE way. Thank you.

Comment: @Shay: I forgot to mention: `singledispatch()` as the name suggests uses only the first argument to dispatch the calls, the type of the second argument is ignored. Whether it is relevant depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an idea:

```
import operator

f_add = {}

def add(a,b):
    return f_add.get(type(a),operator.add)(a,b)


# example
class RGB:
    def __init__(self, r,g,b):
        self.r, self.g, self.b = (r,g,b)

    def __str__(self):
        return '<%s,%s,%s>'%(self.r,self.g,self.b)

f_add[RGB] = lambda a,b: RGB(a.r+b.r,a.g+b.g,a.b+b.b)
print(add(RGB(0.4,0.7,0.1), RGB(0.1, 0.2, 0.5)))
print(add(4,5))
```